# If there are $6$ matrices in $M_{6,6}(\Bbb C)$ such that they all satisfy $A^2=0$, does this imply that at least two of them are similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

If there are $6$ matrices in the vector space $M_{6,6}(\Bbb C)$ such that they all satisfy $A^2=0$, does this imply that at least two of them are similar?

My approach:
Observation: $A^2=0$ implies that all the eigenvalues of these matrices must equal to zero. Which naturally led me to think about the Jordan forms of these, to try and see if there are less than $6$ types of Jordan matrices corresponding to this property as that would be mean that at least two of these matrices should have the same Jordan matrix, and hence must be similar. 
I found that there are more than $6$ types of corresponding Jordan matrices, so my current answer is "not necessarily true", but I need a definite true or false answer here. 
Could someone give me a thought process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is fine. But I don't see how is it that you got more than $6$ types of matrices in Jordan normal for whose square is $0$. There are less than $6$ types and that's why two of them must be similar. Actually, there are only $4$ types: the null matrix and$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$There is no other Jordan matrix whose square is $0$.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Surely there's 6 or more? Because is it not possible that the Jordan matrices could be, say (the numbers denote the sizes of the individual Jordan blocks): a) 1 1 1 1 1 1 b) 1 1 1 1 2 c) 1 1 1 3 d) 1 1 4 e) 1 5 f) 6?

Comment: I assume that there's something about the fact that A^2=0 which forces me to remove some of these options, but I did not notice it. Could you give me some guidance?

Comment: Yes, take your example f. Suppose that $A$ was in Jordan form from the start. Now just take pen and paper and compute $A^2$, $A^3$, $A^4$ etc. It is not a lot of work and very insightful.

Comment: @Vincent I see that when I raise f to some powers, the "diagonal" of 1s will move up rightwards, since f^k = (0+N)^k where N is the matrix of consisting of ones on the first diagonal. I also see that as a result, f^2 =/ = 0. The only thing left is, if A has jordan matrix f, does that mean that A could only have been f from the start?

Comment: @Vectorcalc I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for the clarification. May I ask how you were able to deduce your edit? What thought processes and steps did you take?

Comment: @Vincent Also, even if I was able to remove f), aren't there other Jordan matrices to consider? Such as g) 1 2 3 h) 2 2 2 etc.? How do I deal with these?

Comment: @Vectorcalc The basic ingredient is this: there are only $2$ Jordan blocks whose square is $0$: the null block and $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. No Jordan $J$ block larger than this one is such that $J^2=0$. Actually, if $J$ is a $n\times n$ Jordan block, then the smallest $k$ such that $J^k=0$ is $k=n-1$.

Comment: @Vectorcalc Your last comment confused me. Why do you mention the numbers $2$ and $3$? It's part of the definition of the [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) that “[s]uch a matrix has each non-zero off-diagonal entry equal to $1$, immediately above the main diagonal”.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ah yep I follow that. But looking at your answer I must ask this: If A^2=0, does it always follow that the Jordan matrix J of A must also satisfy J^2=0?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The numbers 2 and 3 etc refer to the sizes of the Jordan blocks. Are my suggestions for g and h impossible constructions?

Comment: @Vectorcalc Since $A$ and $J$ are similar $A^2=0\iff J^2=0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ah I see why that is true now, I should've given it more thought before asking. It's because if A= PJP^-1, then J = P^-1AP and hence, J^2 = P^-1 A^2 P and so if the RHS =0 , then J^2 =0 right?

Comment: @Vectorcalc Indeed.

Comment: @Vectorcalc. Yes your last comment, with the matrix $P$ in it is exactly what I wanted to write in answer to your question somewhere higher up in this comment thread. I am glad you figured it out yourself!

Comment: @Vincent thank you for leaving that out, it has allowed me to develop my abilities as a result.

Comment: Haha, thanks. The real reason was that I was to slow. When I checked in here in MSE again already 10 or so new comments had appeared